# Multiple session factories in spring

Tags: hibernate, spring

How Can i configure multiple session factories that belongs to multiple databases and the beans in one session factory has a relation ship with other i got the following error
@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.mybean references an unknown entity:

Answer (score 1):

You can define multiple session factories but you can't make them share relationships. I don't think hibernate supports cross-database joins.